# How to enforce a contract through an hidden/internal state while being purely functional?

Tags: scala, io, functional-programming, state

#### Use case

Visitors of a website can send me an email by providing their email address and message. To avoid spams, only 2 emails per minute (arbitrary) are allowed before being rate-limited.

Note that this is a learning exercise for me to get more used to functional programming practices so while that might seem overkill, it's a step for me to extend this to more complex systems.

#### Implementation

To do so, the `ContactMailer` class I have so far exposes a single method, `send`, which sends an email based on provided info. It handles all of preparing the mailer/email, enforcing the rate-limit contract, and actually sending the email (using [`courier`](https://github.com/softprops/courier)):

```
import courier._, Defaults._
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue
import scala.concurrent.Future

case class ContactMailer(host: String, port: Int, username: String, password: String) {
  private val mailer = Mailer(host, port).auth(true).as(username, password).startTtls(true)()
  private val envelope = Envelope.from("no-reply" `@` "example.com").to("astorije" `@` "example.com")
  private val queue = Queue[Long]()

  def send(from: String, subject: String, content: String): Future[String] = {
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()

    // If queue is full and oldest known message is < 1 minute ago, rate
    // limit, otherwise send email, drop oldest known timestamp and enqueue
    // the new one
    if (queue.length == 2) {
      val oldest = queue.head

      if (now - oldest < 60 * 1000) return Future("message rate limited")
      else queue.dequeue()
    }
    queue.enqueue(now)

    mailer(envelope.replyTo(from.addr).subject(subject).content(Text(content)))
      .map(_ => "message delivered")
      .recover { case ex => s"message failed: ${ex}" }
  }
}
```

And consumer (another part of the application) calls it like this:

```
scala> val mailer = ContactMailer("smtp.example.com", 25, "username", "password")
mailer: ContactMailer = ContactMailer(smtp.example.com,25,username,password)

scala> mailer.send("foo@bar.com", "One", "...").foreach(println(_))
message delivered

scala> mailer.send("foo@bar.com", "Two", "...").foreach(println(_))
message delivered

scala> mailer.send("foo@bar.com", "Three", "...").foreach(println(_))
message rate limited
```

#### Problem

Perfect, it works. But because I have learned and exclusively used OOP so far, this has all its characteristics: a mutable state, side effects, no referential transparency as calling multiple times with the same inputs can result in different outputs, etc.

- How can I keep this rate-limit in a purely functional programming style?
- If I extract this internal state (the timestamp `queue`) outside of the mailer and request the consumer to provide it such as `def send(previousQueue: Queue[Long], from: String, ...): (Queue[Long], Future[String])`, how can I ensure that the consumer will always respect this rate limit and not send an empty queue to never be rate-limited?
- Is there a way to keep `ContactMailer` focused on what it should do (send an email), and extract this rate limiting into a less specialized layer (a generic rate limiter, whatever it is trying to limit)? Is it agood idea in the first place?
- I read about a lot of generic approaches for this, and still don't know what to choose from: IO monad? State monad? Free monad? Actor system? It seems to me the last one would only shift the problem and be inappropriate in this limited context.
- In general, what would be a good structure for this use case in an FP manner?

In general, I do not know how to approach this. There are a lot of resources out there, but they are either too simplistic and explain the basics that can hardly apply in a real-world situation, or too abstract and theoretical for my little experience to translate them into this example.

I obviously have complete freedom to update the signature of the class(es)/function(s) since I control the whole sequence of operations myself.

*I hope this will not be flagged as opinion-based. I understand why it would feel that way, but I am actually stuck on how to get to a better, concrete implementation. :)*

Comment: Look at how a non-threading [value supply](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/value-supply) works. You may be able to use a similar approach to avoid having to give monadic types to all but the most trivial definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system has two interactions with the outside world, sending emails and rate-limiting actions based on time. Both of these interactions have side effects.

The simplest way to model these would be as external services is using the `IO` monad.

```
// Assuming sending email cannot fail, IO[Either[EmailError, Unit]] otherwise
def sendEmail(email: Email): IO[Unit]

def rateLimit(): IO[Boolean]
```

Your implementation now simply "combines" these two:

```
case object RateLimitReached

def mySend(email: Email): IO[Either[RateLimitReached.type, Unit]] =
  for {
    token  <- rateLimit()
    result <- if (token)
                IO(Left(RateLimitReached))
              else
                sendEmail(email).map(Right)
  } yield result
```

If you call `runAsync` (assuming you use `cats.effect.IO`) on the result of `mySend` right away you might as well use `Future` instead of `IO`, the two will be equivalent for all intent and purposes.

> How can I keep this rate-limit in a purely functional programming style?

Rate limiting is reading the time (a side effect) and mutating a local counter. You could do the latter with a State monad, but that would IMO be over engineered in Scala.

> I read about a lot of generic approaches for this, and still don't know what to choose from: IO monad? State monad? Free monad? Actor system? It seems to me the last one would only shift the problem and be inappropriate in this limited context.

`IO` is the default answer. Actors are based on the `Any => Unit` function type, so if you like purity and type safety you are not going to be friend with actors. The main benefit of `Free` vs `IO` is to be able to get more precise type signature. Returning `IO[Result]` means you could be doing anything inside, with `Free` you could be as precise as you like:

```
def sendEmail(email: Email): Free[EmailEffect, Unit]

def rateLimit(): Free[ReadTheTime,          Boolean]
//                    |                     |
//                    list of side effect   |
//                                          return type

type MyEffect[X] = Either[EmailEffect[X], ReadTheTime[X]]
def mySend(email: Email): Free[MyEffect, Either[RateLimitReached.type, Unit]] =
```

But that extra level of indirection comes with some complexity, and a lot of boilerplate because in the end everything still needs to be interpreted to an `IO[Either[RateLimitReached.type, Unit]]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer, I should be able to explore these solutions. So, is it reasonable to leave the state (queue) be part of the `ContactMailer` class? Doesn't that prevent its immutability/purity?

Comment: Also, I realized shortly after asking the question that another part of the application could reuse the rate limit mechanism (it's not exactly a rate limit, it's a resource caching, but the overall logic of "do not execute if earliest known execution is too recent" is roughly the same). How can I extract this logic into a generic component? I tried a bit and it was again too OOP-like.